# How can I avoid // comments by c lexical analyzer using flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I am writing a lexical analyzer using flex. So how can I make to avoid the single line comments that look like this:

```
//comments
```

What I already used and it didn't work:

```
"//".*\n {};
\/\/(.*) {};
```

Is there any possibility that my symbol "/"(division) is making it ambiguous?

Comment: Please elaborate, what do you mean by `avoid` in this context?

Comment: Also, please never use the phrase "it didn't work" in a problem report or question. It's 100% meaningless. Precisely describe what *did* happen, and if necessary explain how that differs from what you expected.

Comment: I mean ignoring them, so I can separate the tokens, ids, keywords.

Comment: Look at any C-style grammar, that's what they do.

Comment: Either of those patterns will work fine, so whatever problem you have (and don't want to describe) is the result of an interaction with the rest of your scanner rules. A [mre] would make it possible to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you everyone!! I just want to use the lexing to separate the tokens, everytime it finds one, and the line number. For example (1,ID,"main")